# Including external file in UI in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a Shiny application to extract and visualize data in a variety of ways. I have several ui widgets that I want to include tooltip-type text when hovering over the widget. I've successfully used bsTootip and addTooltip from shinyBS. in UI.r

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

    bsTooltip(id='MAPeriod',title='Enter averaging period in days. You may add more than one, separated by a space',placement='right',trigger='hover'),
    bsTooltip(id='wateryear',title='Select one or more water years. Note: there may not be data for your location and year',placement='top',trigger='hover'),
...
```

and in server.r

```
addTooltip(session,'MAPeriod',
 'Enter averaging period in days. You may add more than one, separated by a space','right')

addTooltip(session,'wateryear',
  'Select one or more water years. Note: there may not be data for your location and year','top',trigger='hover')
```

and I've used

`tags$div(title= 'Select one or more water year...', etc.`

These all work fine but when I've added tool tips to many widgets, my code is getting  long and cluttered and hard to follow. I'd like to add the shinyBS versions to external files and have Shiny insert them at the correct location.

I've looked around on-line and haven't found any examples so I'm wondering if this is even possible or whether I just have to live with clutter. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Checking in to see if my solution was what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a new file exclusively for your tooltips, or multiple files for your tooltips.

#### Example Tool Tips File

In this example file, each tooltip and its associated server are wrapped inside a function. This prevents global objects from floating around. We'll use these objects in the next file

**`tooltips.R`**

```r
# Tooltip file

# MA Period Tool Tips
MAPeriod_ui <- function() {
  shinyBS::bsTooltip(
    id = 'MAPeriod',
    title = 'Enter averaging period in days. You may add more than one, separated by a space',
    placement = 'right',
    trigger = 'hover'
  )
}

MAPeriod_server <- function(session) {
  shinyBS::addTooltip(
    session,
    'MAPeriod',
    'Enter averaging period in days. You may add more than one, separated by a space',
    'right'
  )
}

# Other tooltips...
```

#### Using the Tooltips File

To use the tooltips file, we'll source it and place it into a new environment. You can call it whatever you like, here I've called it `tooltips` for simplicity. To access the tooltips you created in that file, simply index the `tooltips` env using `$`, then call the object as a function. Example below.

**`app.R`**

```
library(shiny)

# load the tooltips into a new environment
tooltips <- new.env()
source("tooltips.R", local = tooltips)


ui <- fluidPage(
  # add the tooltips using the new environment we created
  tooltips$MAPeriod_ui()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # add the tooltip server as well, making sure to pass the session to the fxn
  tooltips$MAPeriod_server(session)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Of course, you don't have to store the objects as functions, but its safer this way. You also can create multiple tooltip files and source them all into the `tooltips` env.

Let me know if this makes sense to you!